# Using current each data inside a query in pathFor iron-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, url-routing

Just started playing around with meteor and I'm trying to use `iron-router` for the routing. Here is my **data structure**:

```
team
  _id
  name
  tags:[{name,counter}]
```

And here is the linking I'm trying to use in the **template**

```
{{#each team.tags}}
   <a href="{{ pathFor 'team' _id=../team._id query='search='+this.name }}">{{this.name}} <span class="count-list">{{this.counter}}</span></a> 
{{/each}}
```

And my **router** has:

```
route('/team/:_id')  // And I get the search through the GET property... this.params.query
```

But it doesn't like `query='search='+this.name`, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a `GET` method, this should work:

```
{{#each team.tags}}
   <a href="{{ pathFor 'team' _id=../team._id}}/?search={{this.name}}">{{this.name}} <span class="count-list">{{this.counter}}</span></a> 
{{/each}}
```

Otherwise you would have to build the URL within a helper upfront (or registerHelper function), as spacebars doesn't allow for compound operations.